# Prestashop - MySql Update query script not working

Tags: mysql, prestashop, updating

This is my first question and relates to trying to get an MySql query (I'm an MySql newbie) working as a PHP script in a Prestashop 1.6 environment. I basically want to update a "blank" field called "reference" with data from another field called "id_product" and add a prefix to the data......

To test the query, I first ran my original query (with reference = " ") through the phpadmin backend to make sure it worked and it did:

```
UPDATE ps_product SET reference = CONCAT ("RPR - ",id_product + 10000) where reference = " ";
```

I then edited the "reference" field of a few records and deleted the data so that they were empty.

I then created a php file in the root called "greg.php" that contains the following:

```
<?php

$sql = 'UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'product SET reference = CONCAT ("RPR - ",id_product + 10000) where reference = "";
if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($sql))
    die('error!');
```

I then ran the greg.php script from the browser using the following:

mydomain.com.au/greg.php

It did not work (ie: it didn't update the reference field in the table) or display an error message or any message for that matter.

I am wanting to run this script via Cron on a regular basis...

Comment: Seems like you are missing the closing single quote on the sql declaration 


You should have `$sql = 'UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'product SET reference = CONCAT ("RPR - ",id_product + 10000) where reference = "" ';
`

Answer (score 0):

You blank field is probably not a single space (`' '`) - it's probably an empty string (`''`) or a `null`. So you need to change your `where` clause accordingly:

```
UPDATE ps_product 
SET    reference = CONCAT ('RPR - ', id_product + 10000) 
WHERE  reference = '' OR reference IS NULL;
```

Comment: what is different between `refrence=''` and `reference IS NULL`, why didn't you use only one of them ?

Comment: @Fatemeh An empty string (`''`) is an actual value (albeit an empty one), and can be checked with `=`. `NULL`, on the other hand is that lack of a value, a blank, if you will, and needs to be treated specifically - At least in MySQL. Other databases, such as Oracle Enterprise Database treat `null` and `''` the same way.

Comment: Hi guys, the query that I outlined in my original question works fine using the Mysql admin backend. It's just when I convert it into a php script that it doesn't work....